# set scalar fixed length string attribute in hdf5

Tags: python, attributes, scalar, hdf

I need to add a few string scalar attribute to a HDF file, here is my python:

```
hdf = h5py.File('data.hdf', 'r+')
hdf['program'].attrs['filename'] = '.\\cover.tif'
hdf['program'].attrs['gis'] = 'cover'
hdf.close()
```

this works in that it indeed added the two attributes, but when I examine them in HDFViewer, they have the type: `String, length=variable`, I need to have the actual length in the type, for example: `String, length=5` for 'cover', how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have to use the attrs.create method as shown below:

```
hdf['program'].attrs.create('gis', 'cover', None, dtype='<S5')
```

arguments are:

```
name: 'gis'
data: 'cover'
shape: None
dtype (Numpy dtype): '<S5'
```

that last 5 in the dtype argument is the length of the scalar string. This way, the attribute's type will be `String, length=5`